# How to upload the image/photo to a server using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am trying to upload the image/video to a webserver for iOS. 
The uploading part of this server works fine. I checked it with Android version and I have already implemented the uploading method in Android app.
So I have found some codes for iOS on the stackoverflow.com
First, I am using the following code for uploading image.
But I can't upload at all and get the following result. I am using XCode6.1 on iOS8 SDK.

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x7fe24348d0b0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe2434be120 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=ServerURL, NSErrorFailingURLKey=ServerURL, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
```

Here are the codes that I am using.

```
  NSString* serverURL = @"http://www.myserver.com/file/postMedia.php";
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
  NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
  NSDictionary *param = @{@"userID":@"master",


  [manager POST:serverURL parameters:param constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
   [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"uploadedfile_thumb" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    ....
        });

        return;
    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    ....
 });
```

Certainly, the server works fine.
I have definitely tested with Android code.
So I'd like to know the exact code for iOS.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code uploading an image to the server using AFNetworking:

```
+ (void)uploadImage:(UIImage *)image
             ForUser:(WECUser *)user
    withSuccessBlock:(void (^)(NSDictionary *response))resultBlock
        faliureBlock:(void (^)(NSError *error))faliureBlock {
  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

  formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyyMMddHHmmss";
  NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
  NSString *fileName =
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_image_%@.jpg", dateString];

  NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
    @"user_id" : user._id,
    @"resource_id" : user._id,
    @"functioncode" : @"2000",
    @"app_id" : [WECURLGenerator stringOfAppID],
    @"file_name" : fileName
  };

  NSURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]
      multipartFormRequestWithMethod:
          @"POST" URLString:[WECURLGenerator stringOfImageUploadingBaseURL]
                          parameters:dictionary
           constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
               [formData
                   appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6)
                                     name:@"file1"
                                 fileName:fileName
                                 mimeType:@"jpg"];
           } error:(NULL)];

  AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
      [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

  [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,
                                             id responseObject) {
      NSDictionary *resultDict =
          [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                            error:nil];
      resultBlock(resultDict[@"record"]);
  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      faliureBlock(error);
  }];

  [operation start];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, I am using same code for uploading an image using AFNetworking. But you haven't mentioned how you are picking the image. Because you can not upload an image directly like:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
```

Are you using UIImagepickerController for picking your image?

If YES than see my code;

```
-(IBAction)chooseImg:(id)sender{

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else{
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
NSURL *name = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultBlock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset){
    ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
    NSDictionary *metadata = imageAsset.defaultRepresentation.metadata;
    NSLog(@"Meta:%@",metadata);
    NSString *str = [imageRep filename];
    txtImg.text = str;
};
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
[assetLib assetForURL:name resultBlock:resultBlock failureBlock:nil];
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

NOTE: Here I used metadata to display name of the image,it's not necessary you can skip this.

Than in uploading part:

```
NSString* serverURL = @"http://www.myserver.com/file/postMedia.php";
  //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
  NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
  NSDictionary *param = @{@"userID":@"master",


  [manager POST:serverURL parameters:param constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
   [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"uploadedfile_thumb" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
....
    });

    return;
}

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
....
 });
```

This works for me uploading an image.
Hope it works for you.

Comment: For using ALAssetsLibrary, don't forget to import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>